# Access component outside of Springs "ecosystem"

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application.

For token handling I use some filters - that are no components.

```
public class SecurityAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter
{
  @Autowired
  MyDbLogComp x;   // null

  public SecurityAuthorizationFilter (AuthenticationManager am)
  ...
  protected void doFilterInternal (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException 
  ...
```

...

Now I need to access a component (e.g. for logging to a DB) that I normally @Autowire in other components.

But thats not possible here - the filter is no component - the instance of the object is only null.

How can I access my component inside the filter??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to use spring bean in non-spring bean class

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {
     
      private static ApplicationContext ctx;
     
      @Override
      public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        ctx = appContext;
      }
     
      public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
      }
}
```

now you can get the applicationcontext object by getApplicationContext() this method.

from applicationcontext you can get spring bean objects like this:

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext();
String strFromContext = appCtx.getBean(beanName, String.class);
```